# Unable to enable general Sharing in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

Tags: 18.04, gnome, remote-desktop, file-sharing, gnome-control-center

Attempting to enable general Sharing in the Gnome Settings to then enable and configure file sharing, screen sharing, etc. When I enable Sharing via the master toggle in the top right, nothing changes (I only see the Computer Name portion of the Sharing settings), and when I switch away from the Sharing settings and return the toggle is off again. There are similar questions about screen sharing toggle not staying on, but I can't even get that far. Syslog displays the following after toggling the on/off slider:

```
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.WhoopsiePreferences' requested by ':1.206' (uid=1000 pid=5289 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.WhoopsiePreferences'
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk com.ubuntu.WhoopsiePreferences[1253]: Acquired the name: com.ubuntu.WhoopsiePreferences
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.206' (uid=1000 pid=5289 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk gnome-control-c[5289]: Failed fetch permissions from flatpak permission store: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore was not provided by any .service files
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Apr  6 22:25:54 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Apr  6 22:25:55 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.206' (uid=1000 pid=5289 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
Apr  6 22:25:55 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr  6 22:25:55 ubu-desk dbus-daemon[1253]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr  6 22:25:55 ubu-desk systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr  6 22:25:55 ubu-desk gnome-control-c[5289]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Are there any other logs that would be helpful with this? Looking for some guidance, thanks

Ubuntu 18.04.2 
 4.18.0-17-generic 
 GNOME 3.28.2

Comment: +1, I'm having the same problem here. Tried upgrading everything via "apt upgrade" but to no effect.